# How to construct this HTML table?

Tags: html, jsp

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| header    | header2   | header3                                   |
+           +           +-------------------------------------------+
|           |           | subheader           | subheader           |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  row data1| row data2 | row row1 data 3.1.1 | row row1 data 3.1.2 |
+           +           +---------------------+---------------------+
|           |           | row row2 data 3.2.1 | row row2 data 3.2.2 |
+           +           +---------------------+---------------------+
|           |           | row row3 data 3.3.1 | row row3 data 3.3.2 |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

How do you make such a table in JSP with spring. The row is generated through a loop. The row must contain multiple data rows for the two subheaders. For every row there is multiple table data rows in the subheader. Example: Data 3.1.1 corresponds to data 3.1.2 in the loop.

Comment: Without actually knowing the base data, I can just say, that `colspan` and `rowspan` will be needed.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">header 1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">header 2</td>
        <td colspan="2">header 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>subheader</td>
        <td>subheader</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">rowdata 1</td>
        <td rowspan="3">rowdata 2</td>
        <td>rowdata 3.1.1</td>
        <td>rowdata 3.1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>rowdata 3.2.1</td>
        <td>rowdata 3.2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>rowdata 3.3.1</td>
        <td>rowdata 3.3.2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```